# DOS COPY the first file in a directory

Tags: file, dos, copying

How to copy the first file in any directory starting with .rar extension?

Comment: What platform? What language?...

Comment: Its a DOS batch file that i am trying to create.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will copy "the first .rar" file found" (randomly selected, for all I know) in the current folder to C:\Temp.  I'd consider this to be a template you can start with.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

FOR %%A in (*.rar) do (
   COPY %%A  C:\temp
   GOTO :Exit
)

:Exit
```

Comment: How is a random file the first file? :)

Comment: Technically, it is not random. However, since (with this particular script) we have no real control over what file is the first file listed by the OS, we can assume nothing about which file will be the first returned, so it might as well be random.

Answer (score 0):

Define first: Sorted by date? By name?

Comment: does not matter any sorting is fine.

Comment: He is asking what you mean by "First". First file when they are sorted by date? or first when sorted alphabetically?

Comment: As I mentioned the order does not matter.